# DB2 SQL Server Replication

Tags: sql-server, db2, replication

I need to replicate data from a DB2 database into a SQL Server Database (along the lines of about 80 tables). I can create an SSIS package, to just flat copy the data from one to another pretty easy, but the ammount of records is a couple million, so doing it once takes a while, but for the initial setup its fine. However, I need to do "almost" realtime updates, so this method wont be viable. What would be the best method, and how, to do just add change and delete replication from DB2 to SQL Server?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "best" way to do this kind of replication is to use an application that reads the transaction logs from the source database and then writes the data to the target database.  This is referred to as [Change Data Capture (CDC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_data_capture).

There are many tools that can provide this in a cross-database environment (see the aforementioned Wikipedia article for a list.